# Converting UTC string date to a UTC date

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

I receive the following date string (as UTC) from my api: `"2020-04-01T00:00:00Z"` which is fine.

I then convert this string to a Date object like so: `let formattedstartDate: Date = new Date(data.body.startDate);`

I'm in the UK right now and so this displays as: `Wed Apr 01 2020 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)` however for my users in the USA this displays as: `Tue Mar 31 2020 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (America New_York Standard Time)` as this is of course due to their local browser converting to the different timezones but I want to preserve the GMT/UTC time for all users regardless of where they are.

I want everyone in the world to see it as: `Wed Apr 01 2020 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)`

So I've done a manual conversion back to GMT/UTC using the following:

```
let convertToUtcDate = new Date(formattedstartDate.getUTCFullYear(), formattedstartDate.getUTCMonth(), formattedstartDate.getUTCDate(),  formattedstartDate.getUTCHours(), formattedstartDate.getUTCMinutes(), formattedstartDate.getUTCSeconds());
```

However the users in the USA still see this as `Tue Mar 31 2020 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (America New_York Standard Time)` any ideas as to why?

Answer (score -1):

You can try to get the date from your server in the UK, and then convert the date to a string `let StringDate = dateObjectInUk.toString()`and have the string printed on the screen for your american users.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Problem I have is that my calendar requires it to be as a Date type, so I can't get away with just having a string unfortunately :(

Comment: This won't be a solution but a hack to the original output.

Comment: If your calendar requires a `Date`, I guess there's no workaround other than to somehow tune your calendar library to use the UK TZ explicitly when displaying the value; AFAIK `Date` just holds the UTC timestamp and delivers it in whatever TZ that it was initialized in (which ultimately happens to be the user's own browser/locale TZ). Perhaps also mention your calendar library in the original question so that any possible alternatives can be suggested?